# swift 3 error [_SwiftValue nsli_superitem]

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10, xcode8

After swift 3 conversion I have been getting this error.

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue nsli_superitem]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000a54820'

The code in question is this, it use to work fine with swift 2:

```
let views = ["newView": userLabel]
let widthConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[newView(0)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views)
userMainLabel.addConstraints(widthConstraints)
```

Answer (score 19):

This is a issue with swift 3, where the dictionary is treated as a [String: UIView?]

The fix is to assign the type as not optional

```
let views: [String: UIView] = ["newView": userLabel]
```

Comment: In my case, my view is declared as optional, but it seems that in Swift 2 the compiler implicitly unwrapped that. I like this. Much more predictable. Careful with optionals in dictionaries! hehe

Comment: Thanks. I wasted a day before I figured it out :(